# Unable to Connect to Cassandra from Python code

Tags: python-3.x, linux, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-python-driver

I am not able to connect cassandra from python getting the below error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/script_max_device_count.py", line 232, in <module>
    max_device_count.get_max_device_count_per_partner(partners_dict)
  File "/app/script_max_device_count.py", line 199, in get_max_device_count_per_partner
    session = self.establish_cassandra_connection()
  File "/app/script_max_device_count.py", line 137, in establish_cassandra_connection
    session = Cluster([cassandra_host], port=cassandra_port, auth_provider=auth_provider).connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1358, in connect
    self.control_connection.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2896, in connect
    self._set_new_connection(self._reconnect_internal())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2939, in _reconnect_internal
    raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'1XX.XX.X.X:9042': ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3-E000'")})
```

Version used

```sh
python = 3.7.4
cassandra-driver==3.18.0
```

Linux environment
cassandra installed is

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.3-E000 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

Sample cassandra code connection

```
``
def establish_cassandra_connection(self):
        db_config = DatabaseConfig()
        cassandra_host = db_config.get_cassandra_host()
        cassandra_port = int(db_config.get_cassandra_port())
        cassandra_username = db_config.get_cassandra_username()
        cassandra_password = db_config.get_cassandra_password()
        auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=cassandra_username, password=cassandra_password)
        # connection.setup can have multiple host can be added as a list.
        session = Cluster([cassandra_host], port=cassandra_port, auth_provider=auth_provider).connect()
        logger.info("Cassandra Connection Established.")
        return session 
``
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue this is due to the cassandra driver issue 
cassandra-driver==3.18.0 was not working with linix version of " Cassandra 3.11.3-E000 "

changed version of assandra-driver==3.14.0 in docker image worked fine